# Sync Recrods Between Local And Server using RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to sync some data between local records and the records on the server.
 `syncList` is the entry point for the sync operation with local records. Inside this method i call a method  `syncResultObservable` that would return the Observable object with the records on the server.

Once the records from the server are downloaded I use `flatmap` to transform the sync result into a `map<String, List<String>>` by calling `syncResult (List<String> local, List<String>  server)`.
The resultant `map` should have 2 keys
 `"toAdd":List<String>`
 `"toRemove":List<String>`

Now, i want to perform  separate operations on the each result.
`recordsAddObservable` should add the list from `toAdd` key (i am able to do this).
`recordsRemoveObservable` should remove add the list from `toRemove` key (could not find a way to perform this operation using the same observable).

`recordsAddObservable` operation `toAdd` records is working fine for me. However, i am trying to find a way to call `recordsRemoveObservable` on the map result without causing the whole sync operation to start again for remove case.
Below is the small snippet for 'toAdd' records.

```
public void syncList(final List<String> localData) {
   //fetch the server data
    Observable<Map<String, List<String>>> syncResultObservable = serverDataDownloadObservable(userid)
            .flatMap(new Func1<String[], Observable<Map<String, List<String>>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Map<String, List<String>>> call(String[] serverData) {
                    Map<String, List<String>> map = syncResult(localData, Arrays.asList(serverData));
                    return Observable.just(map);
                }
            });

    syncResultObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Map<String, List<String>>, Observable<List<String>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<String>> call(Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap) {
            List<String> toAdd;
            toAdd = stringListMap.get("toAdd");
            if (toAdd == null || toAdd.isEmpty()) {
                toAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return Observable.just(toAdd);
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<List<String>, Observable<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Result> call(List<String> strings) {
            if (strings.isEmpty() == false) {
                String[] toAdd = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
                Log.i(LogEnum.LogPriority.info, getClass, "syncRecords: will try to add records ", toAdd);
                return apis.recordsAddObservable(userid, toAdd);
            }
                Log.i("Tag", getClass, "syncRecords: no records to add, toAdd);

            Log.i("Tag", getClass, "syncRecords: no records need to be added ");
            return Observable.just(new Result(null, null));
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
             //
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Result result) {
            onCompleted();
        }
    });
}






public Map<String, List<String>> syncResult (List<String> local, List<String>  server) {
    . . .
    . . .

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("toAdd", toAddList);
    map.put("toRemove", toRemoveList);
    return map
}
```

Please let me know if there is a simple way to perform individual operation of different result sets.

Thanks
Big O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it.

```
public void syncList(final List<String> localData) {
   //fetch the server data

         Observable<Map<String, List<String>>> syncResultObservable = serverDataDownloadObservable(userid)
        .flatMap(new Func1<String[], Observable<Map<String, List<String>>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Map<String, List<String>>> call(String[] serverData) {
                Map<String, List<String>> map = syncResult(localData, Arrays.asList(serverData));
                return Observable.just(map);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Map<String, List<String>>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap) {
                    List<String> toAdd = stringListMap.get("toAdd");
                    if (toAdd != null && toAdd.isEmpty() == false) {
                    } else {
                        addRecords(toAdd);
                    }
                    List<String> toRemove = stringListMap.get("toRemove");
                   if (toRemove != null && toRemove.isEmpty() == false) {
                        removeRecords(toRemove);
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/cc6ba2aba19b2cade8f4) a runnable example which, I think, does what you want:

- take a stream of the local values and the server values,
- apply toList on them,
- zip them together and apply the difference calculation logic,
- since you chose to use a map with specific keys, we need to flatten it into keyed streams,
- then create groups based on the two keys,
- and switch over the keys in a flatMap to start the async work required by each case.